# Verificando data dentro de um intervalo no SQL

Tags: sql, dateinterval

Preciso verificar no meu SELECT se o campo ***e.DataTrm*** está entre 30 e 90 dias da data de hoje. Como fazer a condição no CASE ?

```
SELECT 
         e.NmrCnt AS [Contrato]
        ,e.NmrSerie AS [Serie]
        ,e.DataAfr AS [Data Aferição]
        ,e.DataTrm AS [Data Término]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN e.DataTrm < GETDATE() THEN 'Vencida'
            WHEN CONDIÇÃO THEN 'Vence em 30 à 90 dias'
        END AS [Status]
    FROM
    tbl_Eqp e
```

Comment: Qual banco de dados?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o DATEDIFF que te tras a diferença da data pesquisada de acordo com o primeiro parâmetro, no seu caso em dias (DAY).

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, e.DataTrm, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 90 
THEN 'Vencida a ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(DAY, e.DataTrm,GETDATE())) +'dias' ELSE '' END AS [Status]
```

Answer (score 1):

Nesse [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d0910) você vê funcionando

Esquema:

```
create table teste (
NmrCnt varchar(200),
DataTrm DATETIME DEFAULT NULL);

insert into teste VALUES (1, GETDATE());
insert into teste VALUES (2, (dateadd(dd, 30, GETDATE())));
insert into teste VALUES (3, (dateadd(dd, 31, GETDATE())));
insert into teste VALUES (4, (dateadd(dd, 90, GETDATE())));
insert into teste VALUES (5, (dateadd(dd, 91, GETDATE())));
```

SQL:

```
select 
NmrCnt as Contato
,CASE 
            WHEN DataTrm < GETDATE() THEN 'Vencida'
            WHEN (DataTrm < (dateadd(dd, 90, GETDATE())))
              and (DataTrm > (dateadd(dd, 30, GETDATE()))
                                   ) THEN 'Vence em 30 à 90 dias'
            ELSE 'nada'
      END AS [Status]
 from teste
```

Estou usando o SQLServer 2014 se você não se importa.